# macro average and micro average in f-measure for multiclassification task

Tags: machine-learning, nlp

I have 50 files, each containing the sentences of one ambiguous word (words which have one spelling but have more than one meaning). Actually this is a word sense disambiguation project. some files have 2 senses, some 3 and some 4. I disambiguated them with Naive Bayes algorithm. And now I have to calculate f-measure. Because this is a multi classification task, I have to calculate macro average and micro average. Now my question is that, is calculating just one of them is sufficient and scientific or should I calculate both of them? And after calculating f_measure for each file (each ambiguous word), How should I calculate the total f-measure of all of the 50 words so that just have one number at the end? (Is it necessary to calculate that or just calculating for each word separately and have 50 f-measure at the end?). I need it for my thesis, so I want a scientific and correct answer of an expert. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After calculating macro average or micro average for each word, to calculate f-measure for all of the words, we have to multiply each word macro or micro average to the next word average (for all of the 50 words) and divide it to the sum of each word's number of senses.